# app crash on iPhone XS Max with iOS 12.1.4

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I complied an iOS app and try to deploy to different device.
But one of devices is iPhone XS Max with iOS 12.1.4.
When the app open in this device, the app crash immediately.
What should I do?

I am guessing the problem is due to the device is using A12 CPU which require the architect is ARM64e because the app running smooth on the simulator
but i do not find it where to set it in my visual studio.
XCode version 10.2.1
Xamarin iOS version 10.2.4

Comment: whats the crash message, when it failed to build

Comment: i do not have any crash message because i do not own the device for debug.
The crashing procedure is 
1. Open the app
2. Look loading the Splashscreen
3. App Crash

Comment: Did you set the valid provisioning profile for the device, from apple developer account

Comment: Yes, the app is ok in other physical device like iphone6s iphone 7 and ipad. But crashed in XS Max, i still dont have report from XR and XS because I do not have these two model

Comment: checked it may be some library not supporting that Architect.

Comment: Hello @JimmyPun,
You can debug like this :
1) Connect your iPhone to your Mac.

2) Launch Xcode on your Mac.

3) In Xcode, go to Window menu and select "Devices"

4) Select your iPhone that's listed under DEVICES.

5) You will then see your system log for your iPhone in the "Console output" window.

Comment: Hello @JayMehta Thanks but i do not have the device. But I run the test on the app center and having the same result. I am lucky to fix the issue after I removed some unused library project. Maybe some of them are outdated. Anyway, the issue is fixed now. Thanks